# Response.Write webrequest doesn't display XML correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Im trying to get a XML and then response.write it to a page (on my server) so I can get it with an Ajax request (javascript) later.. But when I try this the document comes out as a HTML-page with a node with the XML:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yv9z.jpg

If I go to the url in with my browser it displays the XML correct, so I guess its no erros with the source?

Heres the code thats called on page_load:

```
public void getXML(){

            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("url");
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            req.ContentType= "text/xml charset=utf8";

            Stream streamdata = resp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);

            string serverresponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();
            streamdata.Close();
            resp.Close();

            Response.Write(serverresponse);
        }
```

What am i missing? (yes im new to this!)
tnx

javascript:
    var xmlhttp;

```
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }

          xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML);
            }
          }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api.aspx?METHOD=getXML",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
        xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Oh, im using asp.net, and above code is in codebehind. the aspx page only has this <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="projekt.api" %>

Comment: I think everything is fine there. Its how chrome handles XML file. Did you try with FireFox?

Comment: ye, same :/ when i console.log(xmlhttp.responseText) with ajax the string looks good, but when using xmlhttp.responseXML i get null..

Comment: Please post your javascript code.

Comment: As Kevin mentioned, add ContentType="text/xml" in the .aspx page directive and it should be alright.

Comment: getting server error 500 when doing that :/

Comment: Please post the code behind of api.aspx

Comment: its all above, the only thing it does is calling getXML() on page_load

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML (api.aspx)**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" ContentType="text/xml" %>
```

**CODE BEHIND (api.aspx)**

```
public partial class api: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getXML();
    }


    public void getXML()
    {

        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://webdev.clic.det.nsw.edu.au/Mum12/Public/Sample.xml");
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        req.ContentType = "text/xml charset=utf8";

        Stream streamdata = resp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamdata);

        string serverresponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        streamdata.Close();
        resp.Close();

        Response.Write(serverresponse);
    }
}
```

Thats how I have consumed it in test.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML);
                }
            };

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/testwebsite/api.aspx", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        });



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the xml as expected. Please test and let me know if it helps.

Comment: IT WORKS! it was the ContentType="text/xml" in api.aspx that did it!
oh man! you are my HERO! thank you so veeeeeery much! :)

 <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" **ContentType="text/xml"** %>

Comment: I am going to give +1 to Kevin's solution as technically it is the same thing he mentioned and I am glad that it worked.

Comment: Thanks Tariqulazam.  Good call on the page directive.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the content type of the response in order for browsers to process it correctly:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
```

As Tariqulazam said, the page content is probably okay.  To see what's really happening, look at it with "View Page Source" rather than in the dev tools.

Comment: i have set the .ContentType above it think (3rd row)? If i look at it in Page source it looks as I want! :) but when I try to get it with an Ajax-req the xmlhttp.responseXML gets null, but the xmlhttp.responseText looks like the xml i want :( any idea?

Comment: It looks to me like you're setting the content type of the request, not the response.  I think you want to set resp.ContentType instead of req.ContentType.

Comment: Just shooting from the hip, you could try setting the content type to "text/xml; charset=utf-8" or to "text/xml".  Probably won't make a difference since the error indicates a problem on the server side.